# How to use a toggle switch with Isotope?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have a switch that has a middle, left, and right position. Each time you click the toggle button it changes the variable 'pos'. I have also attached an Isotope grid. I want to make it so that I can filter the grid with the toggle button. I want the middle position to filter all (pos ==1 or 3), the left postion (pos == 2) to filter red, and the right position to filter blue (pos == 4).

jQuery

```
//Toggle
var pos = 1;

$('.toggle').click(function(){
    if(pos === 1){
        $('.button').css('left', '0');
    }else if(pos === 2){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
    }else if(pos === 3){
        $('.button').css('left', '150px');
    }else if(pos === 4){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
        pos = 0;
    }
    pos++;
});



//Isotope Controls
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.color-shape'
  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });


// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjymyzg6/4/

Answer (score 0):

Solved

jQuery

```
var pos = 1;

$('.toggle').click(function(){
    if(pos === 1){
        $('.button').css('left', '0');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '.red' }); 
    }else if(pos === 2){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '' }); 
    }else if(pos === 3){
        $('.button').css('left', '150px');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '.blue' }); 
    }else if(pos === 4){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '' }); 
        pos = 0;
    }
    pos++;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjymyzg6/6/